# How to properly configure security when using Spring Boot version 3.2.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am having trouble understanding SpringSecurity.
I wrote a simple configuration in which there is such a bean:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/home").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll())
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .formLogin(login -> login
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
            );
    return http.build();
}
```

I wrote a controller that should provide authentication:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    private final SecurityService securityService;
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage(){
        return "login.html";
    }
    @PostMapping("/login")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> auth(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password){
        LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password);
        AuthResponse authResponse = securityService.authenticateUser(loginRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authResponse);
    }
}
```

I wrote a controller that should return a page accessible only to authenticated users:

```
@Controller
public class MainPageController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String getMainPage(){
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I wrote an HTML page from which the POST/login method should be invoked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <title>Authorization</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Authorization</h2>
<form action="/login" method="post">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br><br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" required><br><br>
  <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my concept, upon successful authentication, an object of the following class should be returned:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class AuthResponse {
    private String email;
    private String token;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String patronymic;
    private List<String> roles;
}
```

Instead, currently, upon successful authentication, I see in the browser Network tab that the POST/login method returns a status of 302 Found and Type document/Redirect, after which it redirects me to the /home page.
When I call this method through Postman, I also receive an HTML response for the /home page. What could be the reason for this, and how can I properly configure the settings to receive a JSON response with user data, including a JWT token, for further passing in the header?

In my concept, upon successful authentication, an JSON-object, but instead, currently, upon successful authentication, I see in the browser Network tab that the POST/login method returns a status of 302 Found and Type document/Redirect, after which it redirects me to the /home page.
When I call this method through Postman, I also receive an HTML response for the /home page.

Comment: FormLogin as stated in the docs (which i recommend that you read before asking here) is cookie authentication. `JSON response with user data, including a JWT token` Handing out JWTs to browsers is dangerous and there is no such implementation in spring security. So why do you want to build a dangerous login?